# Is there a way to trigger a specific version of a lambda function from a SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Let's say I have multiple versions of an **AWS Lambda** function.

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:test-function:1
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:test-function:2
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:test-function:3
...
...
...
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:test-function:n_version
```

Also I have an **SQS Queue** `arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:account-id:test-queue`

I have one component somewhere whose job is to send messages to the `test-queue`. Is it possible for this component to specify which version of the `test-lambda` function needs to be triggered?

From my limited knowledge, the only possible solution I've came up with is *to create multiple SQS queues*, one for each lambda function version. However, I don't think this meets the requirements of my company from an infrastructure and financial point of view, because we need to replicate this behaviour with multiple lambda functions each with multiple versions increasing every week.

We want to be able to control which version of a given lambda function is going to be triggered from a single SQS queue.

Comment: This can't be done with a single SQS queue.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB. Do you think that the solution I mentioned would work? Do you know some other possible workaround?

Comment: What solution? Using multiple SQS queues?

Comment: Yes, one for each function version. I imagine it should work. I just wonder if there's a better way I cannot think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger/[invoke lambda functions from SQS](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-integrate-aws-lambda-sqs-trigger-via-harshita-verma-1f/).
But sqs works as an event source and you'll have to configure with SQS queue arn as the event source on lambda so it really doesn't know much about the versions.

If you use [aws event source mapping](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping) it gets much easier and you may put your lambda version arn like this -

```
# terraform example
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "example" {
  event_source_arn = aws_sqs_queue.sqs_queue_test.arn
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.example.arn # version specific arn here
}
```

Here, function name can be - `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:account-id:function:test-function:3`.

However keep in mind that the message isn't visible while a lambda get's invoked, and can only be returned to the queue if the lambda fails.

But, the last line of your question says -

> We want to be able to control which version of a given lambda function is going to be triggered from a single SQS queue.

Then there has to be something in between to make the decisions, right?
So you may change your architecture like this -

**SQS -> Lambda_decider -> version specific lambda**.

This way, a lambda checks for data and decides which lambda to invoke. You may [orchestrate multiple lambda with a step function](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/AWS-IaCs-with-Terraform/tree/main/1014.%20step%20function).

Best wishes.